# How to properly sign up for a SE site using the Android app

Tags: support, android-app

I'm quite new to the Android app and don't know how to sign up to a new page.

It's working when I'm trying to vote, the popup opens saying I'm not yet a member and then I can choose to join, but I think there could be another way for this.

What do you think, just wanted to share my thoughts on this.

**EDIT:**
I think there could be somewhere a button/link to sign up for a SE site I'm not yet registered for.  For me it feels strange to vote something, which I'm even after signing up not allowed to because of lacking reputation, just to sign up for this site.

Hope this is a little more precise.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to join a site (within the android app) that you're not a member of without having to do something that requires being a member? Have I got that right?

Comment: @George I *think* OP want a "log in" button/link on any site but not sure.

Comment: Yes something like that @ShadowWizard.
Edited my question.

Comment: OK, clear now. Such thing simply does not exist, the app works in a different way.

Comment: Maybe you make your comment an answer and then we close this question?